# How can i count the number of vertices that are at k distance?

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin

For example, I want to get all vertices that are at a distance of 2 (exactly), like:

```
V1 <--> V2 <--> V3
```

I want to get all V3s for my V1.

This can be done in a query way something like this:

```
select both().both().both.size() from <RID>
```

But my problem is: how can I do this from Java API using TinkerPop without querying directly with a sql query, but using the TinkerPop traversing methods.

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

---

**UPDATE:**

Tried:

OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph(Network.factory.acquire());

```
    try {
        GremlinPipeline<Vertex, Long> pipe = new GremlinPipeline();
        Long count = (pipe.start(graph.getVertex("#12:1")).both()).both().count();
        System.out.println(count);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        graph.rollback();
    } finally {
        graph.shutdown();
    }
```

And the stack trace is:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElement.getRecord(OrientElement.java:326)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.getEdges(OrientVertex.java:798)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.getEdges(OrientVertex.java:780)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.DefaultVertexQuery$DefaultVertexQueryIterable.<init>(DefaultVertexQuery.java:110)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.DefaultVertexQuery.vertices(DefaultVertexQuery.java:84)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.VertexQueryPipe.processNextStart(VertexQueryPipe.java:113)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.VertexQueryPipe.processNextStart(VertexQueryPipe.java:19)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.Pipeline.next(Pipeline.java:115)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.PipeHelper.counter(PipeHelper.java:107)
at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinPipeline.count(GremlinPipeline.java:1534)
at models.service.NetworkFacadeREST.test(NetworkFacadeREST.java:150)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy305.test(Unknown Source)
at models.service.__EJB31_Generated__NetworkFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.test(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
a
Severe:   t org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried finding level 1 friends and it works. But when I try both().both() it gives me the null pointer exception.

I'm still a noob at this and I can't figure out why this happens. Thank you.

---

**UPDATE:**

Tried: `Long count = pipe.start(graph.getVertex("#12:1")).both("Worked").has("recommendation","recommended").count();` and same error; any 2 actions I try to do, it throws this error.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have done more tests like running:

```
pipe.start(graph.getVertex(1)).out();
pipe.start(graph.getVertex(1)).both().both();
```

Those will run with success, but if I try to iterate the same error as above will be called.

```
pipe.next();
for (Object x : pipe) {}
```

But if I iterate into single objects it works, for example:

```
pipe.start(graph.getVertex(1)).getProperty("X");
pipe.next();
```

More then this, methods like `.count()` throw the same stack trace.

Hope someone can make me understand how Gremlin works, seems I can't handle it. (Read their documentation)

Comment: Don't you want to learn how to do this yourself?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem efficiently, and that's my big problem. I'm using OrientDB on Jelastic Cloud service and it's getting really really slow (like 1k vertices interogated with this question in 10 mins)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Gremlin:

```
        OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph(URL, USER, PW);
        try {

            GremlinPipeline<Vertex, Long> pipe = new GremlinPipeline();
            Long count = pipe.start(graph.getVertex("#11:0")).both().both().count();

        } finally {
            graph.shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: It can't retrive both().both()

Comment: What do you mean by it can't? there's an error?
It works here

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer this, was busy. I updated the post with the issue. Hope i gave enough info.

Comment: This line should be:
`Long count = pipe.start(graph.getVertex("#12:1")).both().both().count();`

Comment: Doesn't change a thing :(.

Comment: Try with GratefulDeadConcerts DB to see if you have the problem.

Comment: At your suggestion I tried with GratefulDeadConcerts DB and I found that the problem comes from .count() method. It still throws null pointer exception. Dunno what to try next...

Comment: @ashcrok paste your code somewhere and send me to see what is happening.